# Method 'range' of object'_worksheet failed

Tags: excel, vba

I have this Code in VBA, i just followed a tutorial about the code same code but the results is always showing "Method 'range' of object'_worksheet failed" what is wrong with this code tho?

```
KktkRow = .Range("B5").Value

    For KktkCol = 1 To 39
    .Range(Sheet4.Cells(1, KktkCol).Value).Value = Sheet4.Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol).Value
    Next KktkCol
```

Comment: Without knowing what `Sheet4.Cells(1, KktkCol).Value` is, your question is impossible to answer. Unless that cell contains a range address, that is unlikely to make sense. Please provide a [mcve] rather than a context-free fragment which seems to be inside a `With` block.

Comment: thank you! and sorry for the lack of Explanation! I'm new here since the problem is something new to me also

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> .Range(Sheet4.Cells(1, KktkCol).Value).Value = Sheet4.Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol).Value
> ```

There's a `With` block somewhere *that isn't for `Sheet4`*. Remove the `Sheet4` qualifier and leave the `.` dot operator to make it look like this (assuming the `With` block isn't for `Sheet4` but the source values are on that sheet):

```
.Range(.Cells(1, KktkCol).Value).Value = Sheet4.Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol).Value
```

That way the `.Cells` member calls will consistently be made against the same worksheet that's qualifying this `.Range`; whenever you invoke `.Range` with inner `.Cells`, make sure the inner `.Cells` are on the same worksheet as the outer `.Range`.

This is very similar to a common issue caused by [implicit ActiveSheet references](https://rubberduckvba.com/Inspections/Details/ImplicitActiveSheetReference), when the inner `.Cells` calls aren't qualified at all:

```
.Range(Cells(1, KktkCol).Value).Value = .Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol).Value
       ^^^^^ if the ActiveSheet isn't the same as the parent of .Range ~> error 1004
```

If the `With` block isn't for `Sheet4` but the target cell is, then you need to qualify the `.Range` with it:

```
Sheet4.Range(Sheet4.Cells(1, KktkCol).Value).Value = Sheet4.Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol).Value
```

If the `With` block is for `Sheet4`, then we're missing context. As [John Coleman pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66216666/method-range-of-object-worksheet-failed/66216955#comment117068351_66216666), `Sheet4.Cells(KktkRow, KktkCol)` looks suspicious (are you reading the row number from a cell?).

Comment: Thank you very much, gonna try that debug today, have a good day good sir!